# Can't get value from session with websocket using flask

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I want to pass value from input form on subpage "A" to the backend, then process it, and send back to another subpage "B". I was creating a session value in different ways(using javascript or defining it in app.route), but cant get this value in my socketio event.

Here is how i create session value in js(i want to pass value from input form after button click):

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    ...
    sessionStorage.setItem('testname', $('#test_surname').val());
    ...
});
```

Here is how i was trying to get this value in my socket event:

```
@socketio.on('example_event')
def id_scan(some_value):
    ...
    # first way
    test_name = session.get('testname')
    # second way
    test_name = session['testname']    
...
```

So in first option i get null and in second way i get keyerror. Of course i can easily get this value in jinja.

I also tried to define session value in app.route like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    session['testname'] = 'testname'
```

And i can get this value in jinja but in flask i get same errors

Comment: Have you configured the secret key in the app's config?

Comment: yes i did configure it

Comment: If I am not mistaken. The reason you aren't getting any value in the flask session. Is because that session is application context session. Whereas, "sessionStorage.setItem" stores session state in your browser.  You are not sending anything back to your application context session. Let me know if that helps you, if not I can give a more detailed answer. @m-dnsk

Comment: I think that you are right because when i try to access to this session value(created by js) in app.route i get keyerror too. So what is the right way to create value(taken from the frontend) that can be use between socketio events? I also tried to create session value in socket event from value emited from js but I couldnt get it in another socket event too.

Comment: I do not know enough about socketio to help you with that. But here is a very detailed tutorial. If you read and follow it step by step to completion you should be able to figure out what to do. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent